# Как заполнить всю остальную часть компоненты по-вертикали?

Tags: css, reactjs

У меня есть 2 компоненты: Header и Content. Компонента header имеет вот такой css:

```
.header{
width: 100%;
height: 85px;
background-color: gainsboro;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

Компонента Content имеет стили:

```
.all_main_part{
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, gray, darkseagreen);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Какие свойства надо задать, чтобы компонента Content заняла для начала всю лишнюю высоту окна по вертикали и, если в компоненте будет больше содержания, высота автоматически увеличивалась? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
.all_main_part{
    min-height: calc(100vh - 85px);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)